# Magento 2 custom email template background image

Tags: magento2

I'm working on a custom email .html file, I need to  insert a background image to the Table, image is in /theme/web/images/ folder.
I've search for it, there are solutions but not found what I'm exactly lookig.

How can I add the table background image?